# Grant user permission to multiple projects via TFS api or once via TFS web ui

Tags: tfs

I am using the TFS2018 Api to add build definitions. I have multiple team projects. The user that is using the TFS API doesn't have permission to add build definition in all the projects.

But instead of manually setting it via the TFS web admin site is there a way to grant this user access to all of the team projects either via the api or via the website by doing it once for all projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the user a project collection administrator if they're engaged in administrative tasks across all of the projects in the collection.